# Remove all folders that does not contain a specific name in UNIX

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, zsh

I'm trying to figure out my old skill in *nix.

What I'm trying to achieve is to remove every folders that does not contain a specific word.

This is the listing

```
➜  myfolder: pwd
/user/myfolder

➜  myfolder: ll locale

drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  102 23 Oct 11:13 bn_BD
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  102 23 Oct 11:13 bn_IN
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  102 22 Oct 19:03 en_CA
drwxr-xr-x  8 user  staff  272  9 Dec 16:10 en_US
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  102 22 Oct 19:03 es
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  102 21 Oct 13:18 fr
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  102 23 Oct 11:13 pt
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  102 21 Oct 13:18 ru
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  102 21 Oct 13:18 th_TH
```

Now I want to remove everything except **en_US**

I don't know what is the not in the command

`rm -rf locale/[!somethinghere]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU find (and possibly other versions too), you can use an exclamation mark to reverse a search -- so this will find and delete everything in the current directory *except* 'en_us':

```
find . ! -name 'en_US' -delete
##  If you only want to delete directories:
find . -type d ! -name 'en_US' -delete
##  If you *don't* want recursiveness:
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name 'en_US' -delete
##  If you want to avoid deleting dotfiles:
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name 'en_US' -a ! '.*' -delete
```

Some versions of `find` don't have the `-delete` option; instead you could use one of:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name 'en_US' -exec rm -r '{}' +
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name 'en_US' -a ! '.*' -exec rm -r '{}' +
```

Alternatively, since you mentioned in a comment that you have zsh,

```
setopt extendedglob  ##  this may already be set in you .zshrc
rm ^*en_US*
##  If you only want to delete directories:
rm ^*en_US*(/)
```

Comment: Yours very similar to what I found except I can't seem to use `-delete`?

Comment: What does `find --version` give you? Are you using GNU find, or something else?

Comment: I just use `find` that built-in from my Mac OS X?

Comment: Ahh. You should have specified OSX in your tags (I was wrongly assuming linux). It uses the BSD versions of the various command-line tools, while I'm used to the GNU versions that most linuxen use. Maybe try the new version of the command in the latest version of my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that @evilsoup.. I should have mention that >.<

Comment: So for some reason when I ran this command `ind . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name 'en_US' -exec rm -r '{}' +` my current directory which was git folder now longer a git directory?

Comment: git folders are defined by having a subdirectory called `.git`, which contains all the data for the git version control. Directories starting with a dot are hidden by many applications on unix by default; `find` is an exception in that it doesn't treat dotfiles as being special. By running this command, you will have deleted your `.git` subdirectory. The zsh command would be safe, however.

Comment: Which then I think this is the wrong command I'm using right?

Comment: See the most recent version of my answer for a find command that should ignore hidden directories (the zsh version should ignore them by default).

Comment: By the way, `find` on OS X does have a `-delete` option. Not sure why it didn't work for the OP.

Comment: @slhck maybe I'm on zsh?

Comment: @Ali Zsh doesn't have its own `find` builtin. What does `find --version` say?

Comment: @slhck ```➜  work  find --varsion
find: illegal option -- -
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]```

Answer (score 1):

A three-line solution will work (tested with Linux bash):

```
tar cvf foo $(find locale -name en_US)
rm -fr locale
tar xvf foo
```

That is:

- Save what you want to keep
- Delete original
- Restore what you saved

I played around with something like `find locale \( -name en_US -true \) -o -print | xargs ...`, but this seems more complicated. And more risky, if one's Unix skills are rusty.

Comment: I would prefer the second option only if I can figure out why it keep matching "en_US" too

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using bash expansion:
`rm -rf path/to/!(something.*)`

*Edit:*

As mentioned in comments below, this command works if *extended globbing* format is enabled.

You can enable it by command `shopt -s extglob` in *bash* or `setopt kshglob` in *zsh*.

Comment: I don't know if it is because of `zsh` but I'm getting this - `zsh: no matches found: locale/!(en_US.*)/`

Comment: You need to use `shopt -s extglob` to enable this behaviour in bash; the syntax for zsh is different.

Comment: @evilsoup I'm not sure what is this mean? `shopt -s extglob` ?

Comment: *If* you were using bash, you would have to enter the command `shopt -s extglob` to enable extended globbing, which allows you to use the `!(pattern*)` syntax in this answer. But you are using zsh, which uses a *different* sort of extended glob. I *think* that if you enter the command `setopt kshglob`, you should be able to use this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I end up doing.

`find locale -type d ! -name 'en_US' ! -name 'locale' | xargs rm -rf`

The reason I have to include "locale" as well because the `xargs` returned `locale locale/bn_BD locale/bn_IN locale/en_CA locale/es locale/fr locale/pt locale/ru locale/th_TH`

Now I have these deleted

```
#   deleted:    locale/bn_BD/goggles.webmaker.org.json
#   deleted:    locale/bn_IN/goggles.webmaker.org.json
#   deleted:    locale/en_CA/goggles.webmaker.org.json
#   deleted:    locale/es/goggles.webmaker.org.json
#   deleted:    locale/fr/goggles.webmaker.org.json
#   deleted:    locale/pt/goggles.webmaker.org.json
#   deleted:    locale/ru/goggles.webmaker.org.json
#   deleted:    locale/th_TH/goggles.webmaker.org.json
```

Comment: You shouldn't pipe `find` output to `xargs`, unless you use `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …`.